# TinyMCE and textarea id change

Tags: html, tinymce, textarea

I have a list of textareas. Each textarea is in a separate div:

```
1. < div id="div_textarea1"> <textarea id="textarea1"></textarea> < /div >
2. < div id="div_textarea2"> <textarea id="textarea2"></textarea> < /div >
3. < div id="div_textarea3"> <textarea id="textarea3"></textarea> < /div >
4. < div id="div_textarea4"> <textarea id="textarea4"></textarea> < /div >
```

All those textareas are using the tinyMCE plugin.

Near each textarea, I have a delete button (the button will delete the textarea).

When I click the delete button, the selected textarea will be deleted and the id of other textareas are changed to heve the apropriate number:

```
function deleteTitlenote(titlenote_id)
{
    $('#titlenote_div'+titlenote_id).remove();

    var nodes = document.getElementById('add_titleNote').childNodes.length;
    var n = 0;

    for(var i=1; i<= nodes+1; i++)
    {
        if(document.getElementById("titlenote"+i)!=null)
            {
                    n++;
                    document.getElementById("titlenote"+i).id="titlenote"+n;
            }
    }
}
```

This works fine whe n I have a simple textarea without the tinyMCE plugin, but once I use the mce plugin, even if I change the id, I am acessing the old value of the textarea by calling the new id.

any idea on how to resolve this ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem here is that the id of a textarea corresponds to the id of its tinymce editor instance. To be more precise, when you initialize a tinymce editor the textarea gets hidden and tinymce creates a contenteditable iframe and an editor object which uses this iframe to edit content. The editor obejct gets the id of the html source element (the textarea).
So when you change the textarea id you will either have to shut down all tinymces and reinit them or you will have to reset tinymce editor contents to the tiyncem editor with the corresponding id.